# Can you use grep command inside LSNRCTL listener utility?

Tags: oracle, listener

I need to find out status of listener for particular database. lets say I have 100 of them. I'm not going to go through each of them to check the status.

When I enter LSNRCTL, I get into listner control utility. I want to find out status of listener for particular database. When I type "service grep | DB", it returns no results.

So, can I use grep inside LSNRCTL utility? If YES, how and if NO is there a solution where I can only get service info of listener listening to particular database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can just issue

```
lsnrctl status yourdb
```

I don't think you can use grep inside lsnrctl's command line. if you type help you'll see the available commands.

you can pipe its output to the grep command if needed from the shell. to filter the line with the status it would be

```
$ lsnrctl status yourdb | grep status
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about not going to LSNRCTL at all. I can just do 'lsnrctl status | grep DB' and I works